unable to access demo backend "https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443"
I'm getting CORS error when accessing the demo backend.
Is this supposed to be working?
I'm using "@spartacus/storefront": "~4.3.8",
I added a  proxy.conf.json file in Spartacus project root but didnt work
{
  "/occ/v2/": {
    "target": "https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
